# How can I set top left corner to have (0,0) coordinates in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I want to reverse the coordinate origin in Inkscape to top left corner. By default (0,0) stays at bottom left. Changing it to top left corner will help me in designing a sprite sheet for my game.

Answer (score 12):

You can't. There's an ongoing change to address this an additional work on making it user-configurably. https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170049

It's targetted to the 0.49 release so perhaps if you try a "nightly" it'll have what you're after?

Edit: In version 1.1 (from the inkscape.dev PPA on launchpad.net, as of 2022-02-06) there is an option in `Edit > Preferences > Interface` to set the "Origin at upper left ...", if this is unchecked then the origin is at the lower-left, i.e. like an ordinary x-y graph. So, checking that option will result in the behaviour requested.

Comment: Holy Mackerel, the ticket is still open and it’s already 2015. Well, is there a workaround?

Comment: and its 2016 and still nothing there... is inkscape actually considered alive?

Comment: It's very much alive, as you can see from looking at the bug link, it just seems that this is not being prioritised as you'd like. Indeed there is a patch from one dev attached to that bug report, just that the lead devs decided not to implement a fix in that way. It seems, I'm just a user btw, that it requires a deep refactoring to address this issue.

Comment: It is now 2020 and Inkscape is version 0.92. I have not found out how to set a new origin of the ruler. Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 5):

In Inkscape 1.0 the coordinate system is reversed, so that the top left corner is (0, 0) by default.

You can download the beta version from [the official site](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0beta1/), or install it with snap:

```
snap install inkscape --edge
```